# Replace numbers with % in this array

Tags: javascript

Given the following array

```
[[1,10],[2,500],[3,100]]
```

The resulting array should be with the i[1] normalized to a value between [0-1]

```
[[1,0],[2,1],[3,0.2]]
```

I tried something like

```js
const arr = [[1,10],[2,500],[3,100]] ;
let max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map((o) => { return o[1]; }));
let min = Math.min.apply(Math, arr.map((o) => { return o[1]; }));

console.log(max, min);

let newArr = []

for(let i in arr){
 newArr.push([arr[i][0],(arr[i][1])/max])
}

console.log(newArr);
```

But in this resulting array the min is 0, when it should be 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to respect the minimum value.

```js
const
    array = [[1, 10], [2, 500], [3, 100]],
    max = Math.max(...array.map(([, v]) => v)),
    min = Math.min(...array.map(([, v]) => v)),
    normalized = array.map(([l, r]) => [l, (r - min) / (max - min)]);

console.log(normalized); // [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0.18]]
```